# Commit kafka offset in Aws Lambda Function .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, apache-kafka, aws-lambda

I'm trying to employ AWS Lambda as a consumer for Kafka topic. But I need to be able to commit offset to the topic manually, from out of the box seems it has auto-comit = true. I'm using the following structure:

```
        public async Task ConsumeAsync(KafkaEvent kafkaEvent, ILambdaContext context)
    {

    }
```

But none of the parameters provide a way to commit offset by myself. I believe I could achieve it via Confluent.Kafka library which requires GroupId to be set before commit anything in the form:

```
var config = new ConsumerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "host1:9092,host2:9092",
    GroupId = "foo",
    AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
};
```

But the problem is that when I receive event in Lambda it has the following content. It contains all but not GroupId...

```
    {
   "eventSource":"SelfManagedKafka",
   "bootstrapServers":"b-1.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9092,b-1.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9092,b-1.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9092",
   "records":{
      "p.Vehicles-1":[
         {
            "topic":"p.Vehicles",
            "partition":2,
            "offset":151084,
            "timestamp":1652981862674,
            "timestampType":"CREATE_TIME",
            "key":"eyJpZCI6IjkxMDBGRkZGLTQ4qwktQ0I2My02Mzc2LTIyQ0E3MTJCMDAwMCJ9",
            "value":"eyJpZCQ0NkIwRDYwMDAwIiwiTWFrZSI6IjEwMiBJUk9OV09SS1MsIElOQy4iLCJNb2RlbCI6IjEwMiBJUk9OV09SS1MsIElOQy4iLCJZZWFyIjoyMDE5LCJWSU4iOiI1VkNBQ1JMVDFHSDIyMDMxNCIsIkVsZEVuYWJsZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJFQ01WSU4iOm51bGwsIkZ1ZWxUeXBlSWQiOm51bGwsIl9fb3AiOiJjIiwiX19zb3VyY2VfdHNfbXMiOjE2NTI5ODE4NDkyMzMsIl9fZGVsZXRlZCI6ImZhbHNlIiwiU3RhY2tJZCI6IjQifQ\u003d\u003d",
            "headers":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Where can I get this GroupId.

Comment: How do you know lambda uses consumer groups at all? You can always seek and manually commit a random group id, but if you didn't give one to lambda to begin with, then I think it's storing offsets outside of Kafka

Comment: @OneCricketeer As far as I know every kafka consumer runs inside of consumer group

Comment: That's incorrect. You can disable auto-commits and manually assign partitions and seek a Kafka Consumer from an external offset store, then write offsets to that store as well instead of with the Consumer's commit methods.